# how to use ARIMA model in AWS sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, arima

I have created an ARIMA model for time-series forecasting and want to deploy it so as to use it at the API endpoint. But I am unable to find a way to deploy it on AWS SageMaker, how can I deploy it. I don't want to use DeepAR. Or is there any way to deploy the pickle file on SageMaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Amazon Forecast, which has ARIMA [built in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/aws-forecast-recipe-arima.html)

Or, if you prefer SageMaker, you need to build your own Docker container, publish it to ECR, and then use that

https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.html#The-example